# Как сделать проверку на наличие двух и более одинаковых символа в переменной

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как сделать проверку на наличие двух и более одинаковых символа в переменной.
Например в переменной 12 5@ 12 3@ 12 условие если больше одной @ то выполнять....
javascript - browser automation studio node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можешь сделать так:

```js
const str = '12 5@ 12 3@ 12';
let res = false;

// пример 1:
res = str.split('@').length -1 > 1; // убрать "> 1" для цыфорки
console.log(res);

// пример 2:
const pos = str.indexOf('@')+1;
res = str.indexOf('@', pos) !== -1;
console.log(res);

// пример 2.1, с цыфоркой кол-ва собачек:
res = 0;
for(let pos=0; pos < str.length; pos++){
    const index = str.indexOf('@', pos);
    if(index !== -1){
        pos = index;
        res++;
    }else break;
}
console.log(res);
```

пс. только не говори, что это ты так емаил проверяешь, яжповешуся

лол:

[image: введите сюда бинарный код изображения]

пспс. всё-таки, вот таквот(какниже, встроку) быстрее чутка (`95,174 ops/s ±0.17%`)

```js
if(str.indexOf('@', (str.indexOf('@')+1)) !== -1){
    alert(1);
}
```

Comment: Вот спасибочки тебе. очень выручил)